# Porque al ejecutar mi script sql al llegar a la parte de mis triggers autoincrementables se queda en un bucle?

Tags: sql, oracle

Cree unos triggers para que mis claves primarias sean autoincrementables a la hora de insertar pero a la hora de ejecutar mi script todo ejecuta bien cuando va a ejecutar el primer trigger que es Trigger_idcomisario se queda en un bucle y comienza a generar numeros alguno sabe que es lo que podria estar pasando?

estoy usando oracle 11g express

```
--secuencia 
create sequence Secuencia_comisario
  start with 1
  increment by 1
  nomaxvalue;


--Triggers
CREATE  TRIGGER Trigger_idcomisario;
BEFORE INSERT ON comisario
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
SELECT Secuencia_comisario.NEXTVAL INTO :NEW.id_comisario FROM DUAL;
END;
```

Comment: [Te he votado negativamente porque un exceso de código no es de ayuda.](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2879). Imposible saber a cual trigger te refieres. Por favor, modifica la pregunta para que quede un [mcve]. Aunque es importante que sea completo y verificable, también es importante que sea mínimo.

Comment: supongo que son todos es que cuando ejecuto el script cuando llega a ejecutar el primer trigger que se llama idcomisario comienza a generar numeros automaticamente y se queda en un bucle

Comment: Obviamente estás hablando de otro script que ejecutas también, porue no veo ningún bucle en tu pregunta.  Por favor, simplifica la pregunta. Concéntrate en un trigger e incluye el script que reproduce el problema que observas. También, vendría bien que nos digas cual versión de Oracle usas.

Comment: Ya la organize mejor asi es mas entendible?

Comment: Sí. gracias por simplificarlo. ¿Pero donde está el bucle del que hablas?

Comment: el bucle solo es visible cuando ejecutas el script por eso habia adjuntado todo el codigo

Comment: Me tienes confundido, y sospecho de que lo que tu llamas un bucle no lo es en realidad.  ¿Estás diciendo que cuando ejecutas el script con los `CREATE TRIGGER...`, comienzas a observar numeros?  ¿Como ejecutas el script?  Y si ejecutas el script simplificado que tienes ahora en la pregunta, ¿cual es el resultado? ¿Puedes incluir una copia del resultado en tu pregunta?

Comment: Correcto , Mira Mi script hace esto 1. crea las tablas,2.crea los alter ,3, crea las secuencias y hasta ese punto bien todo excelente luego debe crear los triggers pero al ejecutar el primer trigger en vez de crearlo comienza a generar numeros en la consola 75 76 77 78 79 80 81 y asi sucesivamente cuando lo unico que debia hacer era crear el trigger para que cuando yo insert los datos en una tabla los id se generen automaticamente , a simple vista yo no veo ningun error pero quizas si tenga alguno y por eso me genera el bucle en vez de crear el trigger, lo estoy ejecutando desde sqlcommandline

Comment: Yo veo un problema en el script, pero aun no entiendo lo de los numeros. En fin, te pongo una respuesta para que corrijas las sintaxis, y veremos.

Comment: aqui fijandome bien creo que fue ; que se me fue de mas voy a retificar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aunque no entiendo del todo lo que quieres decir con lo de los números en bucle, lo que sí te puedo decir es que hay por lo menos 2 problemas con tus `CREATE TRIGGER`.

1. No debe haber un punto y coma en esta porción: `CREATE  TRIGGER Trigger_idcomisario;`
2. Es necesario que termines cada sentencia de creación de trigger con un `/`.

Adicionalmente, se puede simpificar un poco la lectura de la secuencia, de modo que la sentencia `CREATE TRIGGER` quedaría de la siguiente forma:

```
CREATE TRIGGER Trigger_idcomisario
BEFORE INSERT ON comisario
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  :NEW.id_comisario := Secuencia_comisario.NEXTVAL;
END;
/
```

Comment: Gracias por el codigo para simplificar , Sabes cual era el problema de mi codigo el / no sabia que despues de declarar un trigger debia ponerlo eso era lo que me generaba los numeros pero el codigo lo tenia bueno y el ; solo fue un error que tuve de tanto tratar de corregir Muchas Gracias por su ayuda ya todo funciona correctamente